# How to get NSArray of localised day-of-week names in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, internationalization, nsdateformatter

How to get NSArray of localised day-of-week names in IOS?

i.e. don't want to have to hardcode them in myself.  Is there an easy way to get this from an IOS class?  All I can think of is to write a method that steps through 7 days and then using the formatter output the Day of Week and collect these up

Comment: I was thinking there was in interface to deliver the list, but I guess I was remembering the one in Qt -- can't find anything in iOS.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter weekdaySymbols]); // or rather, whatever you
                                              // actually want to do with
                                              // the list
[dateFormatter release];
```

Or use `shortWeekdaySymbols` (for Mon, Tue, etc in English) or `veryShortWeekdaySymbols` (for M, T, etc) as you prefer.

Comment: Ah, I looked everywhere except in NSDateFormatter. :(